# How can we modify the date of folder in file explorer

Tags: c#, ntfs, windows-explorer

Is there a way with which we can modify the date of folder in file explorer or is this a part of Ntfs architecture which can't be changed. Assuming there is no NTFS restriction; how can I change the creation time of a folder using c#

Comment: Which date do you want to modify? how do you intend to do it? Programming? What language? This question needs more information

Comment: @Matt The created date of the folder in file explorer . I am not able to change it  . If there is any way i would like that to achieve programmatically using c#

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by changing the date?

Comment: Here is the MSDN for what you are asking http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I guess this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from the MSDN in the comments

```
string n = @"C:\test\dirToChange";
//Create two variables to use to set the time.
DateTime dtime1 = new DateTime(2002, 1, 3);

//Set the creation time to a variable DateTime value.
Directory.SetCreationTime(n, dtime1);
```